# hdf5.h error when installing hdf5 using luarocks

Tags: c, hdf5, luarocks

I am installing hdf5 for lua using luarocks command,

`luarocks --local install hdf5`

Then I got an error;

```
make[1]: Entering directory '/tmp/luarocks_hdf5-2.0.0-1-g0RmEe/lua-hdf5/hdf5'
In file included from <command-line>:0:0:
/usr/include/stdc-predef.h:63:1: fatal error: H5pubconf.h: No such file or directory
 #endif
 ^
compilation terminated.
gcc -E -o C.i -I/tmp/luarocks_hdf5-2.0.0-1-g0RmEe/lua-hdf5/hdf5/../gcc-lua-cdecl/ffi-cdecl C.c
C.c:11:18: fatal error: hdf5.h: No such file or directory
 #include <hdf5.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:33: recipe for target 'C.i' failed
make[1]: *** [C.i] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/tmp/luarocks_hdf5-2.0.0-1-g0RmEe/lua-hdf5/hdf5'
Makefile:44: recipe for target 'hdf5' failed
make: *** [hdf5] Error 2

Error: Build error: Failed building.
```

I am using `lua 5.3` with `luarocks 3.2.0` and `gcc-4.8 compiler` on an `ubuntu 18.04` system.

Can anyone please help out?

Comment: It looks like it expects a hd5 header. You likely need to do something like `apt install libhd5-dev` or equivalent for your os.

Comment: I already have done it using `sudo apt-get install libhdf5-dev` and `libhdf5-dev` is already the newest version (1.10.0-patch1+docs-4). Can you please look for some other solution @PiRocks ?

Comment: These kind of things are typically difficult to figure out via the comments section, because they are highly dependent in your particular setup. There are a couple of things you need to find out:
1. Does hd5.h exist on your system?(find  and locate and apt-file can be useful for this)
2. Where is it?
3. Is luarocks finding it correctly?(I would look at the build directory made by luarocks in /tmp/ to find out if it has or not  )
4. If not is this a bug?(If you think this is a bug can you reproduce it in some kind of dockerfile or similar?)

Comment: Another thing that occurs to me is that your compiler is quite old, and that this may be a bug which no one else gas noticed b/c they have a new compiler